# getting Value from scala enumeration

Tags: scala, enumeration

say i have enumeration like this

```
object SimpleEnum extends Enumeration{
 val ONE = Value(1)
 val TWO = Value(2)
 val THREE = Value(3)
 etc...
}
```

also i've a class which i want to be extending Ordered[SimpleEnum]

```
class SimpleClass(se: SimpleEnum) extends Ordered[SimpleEnum] {
  override def compare(that: SimpleEnum): Int = this.se.[here i want to get instance of SimpleEnum, just like i used to do in java, but unfortunately it's not possible]
}
```

So in SimpleClass i just need to get the Value attached to corresponding SimpleEnum val.

[image]

In java i'm able to declare a variable on enum and access an actual value corresponding to it by this var, in scala i'm looking for a way to get an instance of enum and reach out for its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, use `id` method.

```
scala> object E extends Enumeration { 
  val A = Value(1)
  val B = Value(7)
  val C = Value(2)
}
defined object E

scala> E.A.id
res7: Int = 1

scala> E.B.id
res8: Int = 7

scala> E.C.id
res9: Int = 2
```

`Enumeration` values can also be easly compared

```
scala> E.A < E.B
res10: Boolean = true

scala> E.C < E.B
res11: Boolean = true

scala> E.B < E.A
res12: Boolean = false
```

Refer to [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Enumeration$Value) for more

### Edit

Your code in the picture is wrong. Firstly, as in your original code (that is not in the picture), `SimpleEnum` should be an `object`, not a `class`. As soon as you make that change your code won't compile and that should ring a bell.

You want `SimpleClass` to be able to wrap your enum values. Type of those values (i.e. `ONE`, `TWO`, `THREE`) is not `SimpleEnum`, it is `SimpleEnum.Value`. Objects of this type have `id` method.

```
class SimpleClass(se: SimpleEnum.Value) extends Ordered[SimpleEnum.Value] {
  override def compare(that: SimpleEnum.Value): Int = se.id
}
```

A common thing to do is to declare a type alias for `Value` with exact same name as the enum object. Then you can import this type and use it

```
object SimpleEnum extends Enumeration {
  type SimpleEnum = Value

  val ONE = Value(1)
  val TWO = Value(2)
  val THREE = Value(3)
}

import SimpleEnum.SimpleEnum

class SimpleClass(se: SimpleEnum) extends Ordered[SimpleEnum] {
  override def compare(that: SimpleEnum): Int = se.id
}
```

Note that `Enumeration#Value` already implements `Ordered[Value]`. You can verify it in the docs that I linked earlier.

There is no classic java `enum` in scala, but because the language is so cool, it was possible to create a regular class called `Enumeration` that with some tricks allows for similar behavior.

Comment: Yeah i know about .id method but it's unavailable here. I attached a pic to my question.

Comment: See my edit. You are using your enum in a wrong way.

Comment: Note that Enumeration#Value already implements Ordered[Value]. You can verify it in the docs that I linked earlier. - yeah, but comparison is more complex in my case. Thx that's exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Values can be defined as strings. This scenario would seem to be incompatible with .id().

Comment: @AndrewNorman Values still have id that is an `Int`, even if they are defined as string. Anyway each scenario can be handled somehow, it is only important to understand how Enumeration works in scala. Anyway, my anwer helped the OP, it is correct, and I see no reason to downvote...

Comment: @Łukasz that is true, but if you are defining the id as strings, it was probably to define values that persist or are referenced outside the enumeration.That would be the reason that a code generated int val wouldn't be acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

The question is already answered but my approach is the following:

```
object SimpleEnum extends Enumeration{
 type SimpleEnum = Value
    val ONE = Value(1)
    val TWO = Value(2)
    val THREE = Value(3)
    etc...
}

class SimpleClass(val i : Int){
    def getNumber() {
        import SimpleEnum._
        SimpleEnum(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you'd realized that the question is already answered, what made you add your own that brings nothing new to the table, except renaming.